# How to display Base Currency Grand Total on Shipping Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, grand-total

Base Currency Grand Total is already showing on the payment & review page on checkout with below error.

```
knockout.js:3381 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return getBaseValue() }"
Message: getBaseValue is not defined
    at text (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:3:57)
    at update (knockout.js:4659)
```

[image]

HTML responsible to show base Currency Grand Total is:

`/vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html`

Code:

```
<!-- ko if: isBaseGrandTotalDisplayNeeded() && isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals charge" style="border-top: 1px solid;">
    <th class="mark" data-bind="i18n: basicCurrencyMessage" scope="row" style="font-weight: bold;color: #A82682;"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getBaseValue(), attr: {'data-th': basicCurrencyMessage}" style="font-weight: bold;color: #A82682;"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I want to show the same Base Currency Grand Total on Shipping Page, but it is not working.

I have added the same code to this file but it is not showing the base Currency Grand Total.

Code:

```
<span class="mark" data-bind="i18n: basicCurrencyMessage" scope="" style="font-weight: bold;color: #A82682;"></span>
<span class="price" data-bind="text: getBaseValue(), attr: {'data-th': basicCurrencyMessage}" style="font-weight: bold;color: #A82682;"></span>
```

File:

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/estimation.html`

Note: it is bad practice to update files inside the vendor folder. I will override these files after testing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough just to copy the code because there are some checks in KnockoutJs.

The template 'grand-total.html' is called in:

`vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total.js`

Here you will find the definition of the **getBaseValue()** function on line **49**. You should look for the js file called in the section you want (**estimation.html**) and add **getBaseValue()** function.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is using in **grand-total,html** template. I have used in  **estimation.html** template using `<!-- ko template:Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/grand-total" -->
<span data-bind="text: getBaseValue()"></span>
<!-- /ko -->` still it is not working